# Seguridad en aplicacion AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, seguridad

Estoy desarrollando mi aplicación web con angularjs, anteriormente trabaje con angularjs en Ionic. En las aplicaciones moviles utilizaba un plugin de encryptación que impedia poder ver el codigo fuente y con eso pasaba seguridad. Sin embargo, esta vez estoy en un desarrollo web con angularjs y tan solo con "Ver codigo fuente", puedo acceder a las constantes, a los controladores, etc etc.

Mi consulta es la siguiente ¿Como puedo agregar seguridad a mis archivos de la aplicación?

Comment: El esconder el código no lo va a hacer más seguro, la [seguridad por oscuridad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seguridad_por_oscuridad#Argumentos_contra_la_seguridad_por_oscuridad) es siempre una mala idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque no hay forma de ocultar los script porque este se carga en el navagador lo que lo hace publico, lo que puedes hacer es ofuscarlo haciendo el codigo casi imposible de leer.

Existen herramientas como [javascriptobfuscator](https://javascriptobfuscator.herokuapp.com/) que te pueden ayudar. Lo unico que tienes que tener encuenta que esa ofuscacion puede hacer tu codigo un poco mas lento debido a que hace modificacines a tu codigo.

Como estas utilizando angular es bueno notar que tienes que asegurarte de definir las dependencias como array, no como parámetros. Por ejemplo si ofuscas el siguiente código, te lanzara un error:

```
app.controller("ctrl",function($scope, $http)){
    // codigo
})
```

Te fallara porquel a ofuscacion cambiara el nombre de `$scope` a `__b`, por ejemplo, por lo que angular no podra encontrar esa dependencia y te lanzara un error. Utilizando la sintaxis de array te funcionara bien:

```
app.controller("ctrl",['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)){
    // codigo
}])
```

Ahora te funcionara debido a que angular sabra cual dependencia injectar en base a los nombres del array.

Comment: El minimizar el código no es suficiente ofuscación?

Comment: No. La consola de google chrome tiene una opcion que te permite darle formato aun script por lo que no te ayudaria de nada.

Comment: Le da formato, pero no recupera los nombres de las variables y o métodos. Sigue siendo bastante ilegible. De hecho ese ofuscador perdería parte de la gracia si tras ofuscar tratas de minimizar el código, con lo que una aplicación grande puede tener problemas de tiempo de carga

Comment: Creo que estamos hablando de lo mismo con diferentes terminos. Recuerda que si un minimizador le cambia los nombres a las variables tambien se considera ofuscador.

Comment: Es posible, yo estaba dando por hecho que un minimizador renombrará todas las variables, funciones y clases internas del código para ahorrar espacio. Por eso opinaba que al optimizar el código ya iba a ofuscarlo lo suficiente

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda!, por suerte estoy declarando las dependencias dentro del array!